# Регулярное выражение: найти все числа не по краям строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, составить регулярное выражение.
Например:

```
test = '12asiudas8787hajshd986q756tgs87ta7d6-12js01'
test.scan(регулярное_выражение)
```

В результате должно получиться

```
["8787", "986", "756", "87", "7", "6", "12"]
```

Иными словами регулярное выражение как /\d+/, только чтобы числа по краям строки игнорировались.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
test = '12asiudas8787hajshd986q756tgs87ta7d6-12js01'
arr = []
test.scan(/(?<=[^\d])(\d+)(?=[^\d])/) do |match|
  arr << match[0]
end
p arr
```

Answer (score 2):

Помогут positive look-ahead и positive look-behind:

```
/(?<=\D)\d+(?=\D)/
```

Comment: В принятом ответе с точностью до расположения групп и `\D`/`[^\d]` то же самое. Просто сообщаю.

Comment: Все ответы на все везде те же самые.

Answer (score 1):

```
Reg1=/ [[:digit:]]+
       [^[:digit:]]+([[:digit:]]+)
       [^[:digit:]]+([[:digit:]]+)
       [^[:digit:]]+([[:digit:]]+)
       [^[:digit:]]+([[:digit:]]+)
       [^[:digit:]]+([[:digit:]]+)
       [^[:digit:]]+([[:digit:]]+)
       [^[:digit:]]+([[:digit:]]+)/x
line = '12asiudas8787hajshd986q756tgs87ta7d6-12js01'
m = Reg1.match(line)
puts m[1..7]
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса будет крайне вам признателен за экспертный комментарий к коду.